# Please explain this php expression "!$variable"

Tags: php, operators

What does an exclamaton mark in front of a variable mean? And how is it being used in this piece of code?

EDIT: From the answers so far I suspect that I also should mention that this code is in a function where one of the parameters is $mytype ....would this be a way of checking if $mytype was passed?  - Thanks to all of the responders so far.

```
 $myclass = null;

    if ($mytype == null && ($PAGE->pagetype <> 'site-index' && $PAGE->pagetype <>'admin-index')) {
        return $myclass;
    }
    elseif ($mytype == null && ($PAGE->pagetype == 'site-index' || $PAGE->pagetype =='admin-index')) {
        $myclass = ' active_tree_node';
        return $myclass;
    }
    elseif (!$mytype == null && ($PAGE->pagetype == 'site-index' || $PAGE->pagetype =='admin-index')) {
        return $myclass;
    }`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!` before variable negates it's value

this statement is actually same as `!$mytype` since `FALSE == NULL`

```
!$mytype == null
```

statement will return `TRUE` if `$mytype` contains one of these:

- `TRUE`
- number other than zero
- non-empty string

Answer (score 4):

The exclamation mark in PHP means `not`:

```
if($var)
```

means if `$var` is not null or zero or false while

```
if(!$var)
```

means if `$var` IS null or zero or false.

Think of it as a query along the lines of:

```
select someColumn where id = 3
```

and

```
select someColumn where id != 3
```

Answer (score 3):

`!` negates the value of whatever it's put in front of. So the code you've posted checks to see if the negated value of `$mytype` is `==` to `null`.

```
return true; //true
return !true; //false

return false; //false
return !false; //true

return (4 > 10); //false
return !(4 < 10); //true

return true == false; //false
return !true == false; //true

return true XOR true; //false
return !true XOR true; //true
return !true XOR true; //false
```

Answer (score 1):

```php
elseif (!$mytype == null && ($PAGE->pagetype == 'site-index' || $PAGE->pagetype =='admin-index')) {
    return $myclass;
}
```

The above `!$mytype == null` is so wrong. `!$mytype` means that if the variable evaluates to false or is null, then the condition will execute.

However the extra `== null` is unnecessary and is basically saying `if (false == null)` or `if (null == null)`

Comment: This is exactly what I thought!!  I posted because I wondered if there is some other reason. I'll give it a few days to see if it turns up some extremely revealing PHP quirk or major misunderstanding on my part.

Answer (score 0):

`!$variable` used with `If` condition to check variable is `Nul`l or Not

For example

```
if(!$var)
```

means if `$var` IS null.

Comment: hmmm.. it would seem to me that `$mytype == null` is the same as `!$mytype == null` ... I did not mention that this code is in a function....would this be a way of checking if `$mytype` was passed?